# Excel 2010 - Stop solver when trying to find subset that adds to total

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I found how to use the solver to find a subset of numbers that adds to a given total - very nice.

Now, I sometimes am not certain there is a solution.  When Excel takes too long, is there a way to stop the solver before it runs through every possible iteration?  With a relatively small set of numbers (25) the solver has been running now for over 20 minutes.  I otherwise don't have issues with Excel ever slowing down even when really pushing it with calculations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Have you tried to click `ESC`?

Take a look at "[Excel Solver - Pause or stop Solver](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-pause-or-stop-solver)" please:

```
If you press ESC while Solver is solving, the Show Trial Solution dialog box appears.  Do one of the following:

    Click Stop to stop the solution process.  TheSolver Results dialog appears with a message that Solver stopped at your request.
    Click Continue to allow Solver to continue solving until you press ESC again, a Solving Limit is reached, or a solution is found.

If Solver reaches one of the Solving Limits (Max Time, Iterations, Max Subproblems or Max Feasible Solutions) while solving a problem, the Show Trial Solution dialog box appears.  Do one of the following:

    Click Stop to stop the solution process.  The Solver Results dialog appears with a message that the limit was reached.
    Click Continue to allow Solver to continue solving without the limit mentioned in the dialog box message.  If another limit is reached, the Show Trial Solutiondialog box will re-appear, once for each limit.
```